# How/where to get WGS84 height (height above ellipsoid) for a set of coordinates

Tags: qgis, python

I am using the NOAA coastal relief model database and their bathymetry for the zone I am interested in is referenced to the EGM2008 geoid. I want to convert this datum to Mean Sea Level and brief research online suggests that I can do that by subtracting EGM2008 height from the WGS84 ellipsoid height, however I cannot find a simple way to get these height values. I have a very large CSV file with coordinates that need to be used. I am a beginner to GIS.

Answer (score 1):

vDatum will do those conversion and vDatum gives you a lot of control over the conversion process.  vDatum will convert to or from any number of tidal datums, orthometric datums, and ellipsoidal datums.  [See the datum tutorial here](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/datums.html).

There is an [online version of vDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/vdatumweb/) which will accept a CSV file.  You can also [download a Java executable](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/) which will allow for some command-line tools, convert ascii raster file vertical datums, as well as CSV.

Can you clarify why you want local mean sea level and not an [NAVD88](https://geodesy.noaa.gov/datums/vertical/north-american-vertical-datum-1988.shtml) elevation?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you looking for

https://www.unavco.org/software/geodetic-utilities/geoid-height-calculator/geoid-height-calculator.html

You can load individual points or a csv file. Just check the specific structure.